# ionic emulate android error in Ionic2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and when I try to `ionic emulate android` I get this error in the terminal:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.651 secs

Error: /home/xxxx/Desktop/myCoolApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /home/xxxx/Android/Sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Please install Android target: "android-23".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /home/xxxx/Android/Sdk/tools/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

In `platforms/android/gradle/project.properties` file (under my ionic2 project folder) I have `target=android-23`.

In the last line of `platforms/android/gradle/AndroidManifest.xml` file I have `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`.

This is my SDK_Manager:
[image]

Maybe If I downgrade from Android 24 to Android 23 it would work (didn't try) but I don't think it's the right way to solve this problem.

So I tried changing the previous 2 files in this way:

```
In `platforms/android/gradle/project.properties` file (under my ionic2 project folder) I set `target=android-24`.
In the last line of `platforms/android/gradle/AndroidManifest` file I set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />`.
```

But I'm still getting the same error, what am I missing?

FYI:

android `list targets` gives me this:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-24"
     Name: Android 7.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 24
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed sdk properly?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In addition to `platforms/android/gradle/AndroidManifest.xml` and `platforms/android/gradle/project.properties` I also had to change `target=android-23` to `target=android-24` inside `platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties`.